# Sliding across piano keys (swift/iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app (piano) that has a series of buttons that each has a different mp3. The screen shows 12 buttons (piano keys) and I want the user to be able to play an individual sound or swipe across a couple to hear multiple. Just like a real piano. I've seen many apps do this but mine seems to have a problem when the user slides across multiple buttons quickly. At the same speed, other apps will play all the notes, but mine will skip a few. Thank you for any help! This will make all the difference in my app!

A couple quick notes about this code:

-I just have the bare bones here to save space

-I just showed 6 audio players, but you get the idea

-the locationInNote1...Note2...Note3 is just showing 6 here to save place, but you get the idea

-"note1" in the button action is a string that can be changed when the user selects different octaves to play from, but its just a #, so the audio files ultimately are 1.mp3, 2.mp3, etc.

-the button action playNote1 is the same as the other button actions so i didn't repeat them all there.

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer2 = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer3 = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer4 = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer5 = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer6 = AVAudioPlayer()

func playNote(for locationInView: CGPoint) {
    let locationInNote1 = note1Button.convert(locationInView, from: view)
    let locationInNote2 = note2Button.convert(locationInView, from: view)
    let locationInNote3 = note3Button.convert(locationInView, from: view)
    let locationInNote4 = note4Button.convert(locationInView, from: view)
    let locationInNote5 = note5Button.convert(locationInView, from: view)
    let locationInNote6 = note6Button.convert(locationInView, from: view)

    if note1Button.point(inside: locationInButton1, with: nil) {
        playNote1(self)
    }

    if note2Button.point(inside: locationInButton2, with: nil) {
        playNote2(self)
    }

    if note3Button.point(inside: locationInButton3, with: nil) {
        playNote3(self)
    }

    if note4Button.point(inside: locationInButton4, with: nil) {
        playNote4(self)
    }

    if note5Button.point(inside: locationInButton5, with: nil) {
        playNote5(self)
    }

    if note6Button.point(inside: locationInButton6, with: nil) {
        playNote6(self)
    }
}

@IBAction func playNote1(_ sender: Any) {
  let note1mp3 = note1
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: note1mp3, ofType: "mp3") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }    
        }
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

Comment: FYI - use `if/else` in your `playNote` method since a point can only be in one button at a time.

Comment: Why load each mp3 from the bundle and create a new audio player over and over each time a note should be played? That's very inefficient.

Comment: Why have 6 duplicate `playNoteX` methods? Just have one and pass the note number so the correct mp3 file can be accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to hopefully:

- Improve your code
- Make your code simpler
- Fix the problem you're having

In this example, I'll just put 3 audio players. 
I'll try to make it as straight forward as possible...

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var audioPlayer2 = AVAudioPlayer()
    var audioPlayer3 = AVAudioPlayer()
    @IBOutlet var notes: [UIButton]!
    let references = [note1, note2, note3]

    @IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        play(note: notes.index(of: sender)! + 1)
    }

    func play(note: Int) {
        let reference = references[note - 1]
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: reference, ofType: "mp3") {      
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

*@IBOutlet var notes: [UIButton]!*
This is an **Outlet Collection** of buttons. To make this, connect a button but select **Outlet Collection** instead of just **Outlet**. Make sure you **connect each button in order** (1, 2, 3), otherwise it will break!

*let references = [note1, note2, note3]*
This is an array of references to each of the note files. This is so that we only need one function to play a note.

*@IBAction func notePressed(_ :sender:)*
This function gets called by the buttons. For each button, connect the **Touch Drag Enter** (for sliding along notes) and **Touch Down** actions. You can add other ones if you want. The functions compares the **sender** and **notes Outlet Collection** to find out which note was pressed, then passes it to the *func play(:note:)* function.

*func play(:note:)*
This function takes the note number, and plays the corresponding file. It's almost identical to your original one, but instead of having a fixed note, it has one that is passed by the *@IBAction func notePressed(_ :sender:)* method.

I hope this is helpful, good luck!